# Wrong images are showing up in UITableviewcell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I am using GCD to load images from web into my `UITableViewCell`. But, wrong images are showing up.

Here is code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.newsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"newsTableCell"];
    NSString *user = [usernames objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *stat = [statistics objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *imagePath = [appDelegate.URL stringByAppendingString:@"ImageName"];
    UIImageView *userImageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:80];


        NSString *imagePath1 = [imagePath stringByAppendingString:[imagepaths objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imagePath1];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
        userImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
         dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [userImageView setImage:img];
         });
    });
 return cell
}
```

Please let me know, where I am going wrong.

Comment: Ramu Pasupuleti can you please elaborate on what exactly solved your issue? as I am having the exact same issue

Comment: @Jonathan, I am loading the images using tags. so, I replaced that with a custom UITableViewCell class.

Comment: oh okay, but wont cell would've solved the issue as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using at all your `cell` variable, you are setting images on an `UIImageView` which comes from `self.view`. The images will never be set correctly on the cells of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now the images appearing correctly, but images are loading only while scrolling.

Comment: This is the recommended behaviour, mobile devices are constrained in bandwidth and RAM so it would hurt the user to download say hundreds of pictures just because the header of the table was displayed. However, if you absolutely need to do this I would recommend retrieving the images out of the cell creation method (maybe in viewDidAppear) and then only assign them to the visible cell whenever they finish loading or when the table is scrolled and a new cell is dequeued for an already downloaded image.