# UIImage in UITableView displaying the other cell's image for a second

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to load image asynchronously in a UIImage that resides in a table view cell. sometimes it shows the image from another cell for a second before it displays the correct one.

This is the code I am using

```
[[TMCache sharedCache] objectForKey:post[@"gif"] block:^(TMCache *cache, NSString *key, id object) {
                if (object) {
                    if ([self isRowZeroVisible:indexPath.section]) {
                        [GIFLoader loadGIFData:object to:postGif for:feedTableView];
                    }
                    return;
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    
                    __block NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:post[@"gif"]];
                    NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
                    
                    OHURLLoader* loader = [OHURLLoader URLLoaderWithRequest:req];
                    [loader startRequestWithResponseHandler:nil
                    progress:nil
                    completion:^(NSData* receivedData, NSInteger httpStatusCode) {
                        if ([self isRowZeroVisible:indexPath.section]) {
                            
                            [GIFLoader loadGIFData:receivedData to:postGif for:feedTableView];
                        }
                        [[TMCache sharedCache] setObject:receivedData forKey:post[@"gif"]];
                    } errorHandler:nil];
                });

            }];


[GIFLoader loadGIFData:receivedData to:postGif for:feedTableView]; is a method I created that loads GIFs in a uiimageview. it does that in a background thread and then assigns the Image in the main thread though.
```

Are there certain practices that I need to follow for async loading?

I am not sure what is wrong with my code. any help would be highly appreciated

## edit

```
//Loading stuff into tableView
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        
        //Type of Cells
        static NSString *simpleTableImageIdentifier = @"gifCell";
        static NSString *simpleTableBodyIdentifier = @"bodyCell";
        static NSString *simpleTableActionsIdentifier = @"actionsCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
        
        //Data that goes in the cell
        NSDictionary *post = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        
        //User info
        UIImageView *userAvatar;
        UILabel *postUserFullNameLabel;
        UILabel *postUsername;
        
        //GIF Date
        OHAttributedLabel* gifDate = nil;
        NSMutableAttributedString* gifDateString;
        
        //Feed GIF
        NSString *gifBody = [[NSString alloc]init];
        OHAttributedLabel* attrLabel = nil;
        NSMutableAttributedString* mas;
        
        //Location
        OHAttributedLabel* gifLocation = nil;
        NSMutableAttributedString* gifLocationString;
        UILabel *locationBg;
        
        //Buttons
        UIButton *btn1 =[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11,0,50,30)];
        UIButton *btn2 =[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(69,0,50,30)];
        UIButton *btn3 =[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(259,0,50,30)];
        
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableImageIdentifier];
            
            if (cell == nil){
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableImageIdentifier];
            }
            
            __block UIImageView *postGif= (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:104];
            
            postGif.image = nil;
            
            [[TMCache sharedCache] objectForKey:post[@"gif"] block:^(TMCache *cache, NSString *key, id object) {
                if (object) {
                    if ([self isRowZeroVisible:indexPath.section]) {
                        [GIFLoader loadGIFData:object to:postGif for:feedTableView];
                    }
                    return;
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    
                    __block NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:post[@"gif"]];
                    NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
                    
                    OHURLLoader* loader = [OHURLLoader URLLoaderWithRequest:req];
                    [loader startRequestWithResponseHandler:nil
                    progress:nil
                    completion:^(NSData* receivedData, NSInteger httpStatusCode) {
                        if ([self isRowZeroVisible:indexPath.section]) {
                            
                            [GIFLoader loadGIFData:receivedData to:postGif for:feedTableView];
                        }
                        [[TMCache sharedCache] setObject:receivedData forKey:post[@"gif"]];
                    } errorHandler:nil];
                });

            }];
            
            postGif.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0;
            postGif.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            postGif.clipsToBounds = YES;
            
            
            locationBg = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:106];
            
            
            userAvatar = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
            if ([post [@"user_avatar"] length ] > 0) {
                NSString *img = [@"https://d1f7i732a4e7fw.cloudfront.net/" stringByAppendingString:post [@"user_avatar"]];
                [userAvatar setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:img] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"userDefaultPicture.png"]];
            }else{
                userAvatar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"userDefaultPicture.png"];
            }
            userAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = 18.0;
            userAvatar.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
            userAvatar.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor lightGrayColor]);
            userAvatar.clipsToBounds = YES;
            
            
            postUserFullNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
            postUserFullNameLabel.text = post[@"user_fullname"];
            
            
            
            postUsername = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
            postUsername.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",post[@"user_username"]];
        
            
            gifDate = [[OHAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(246,9,60,21)];
            gifDate.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
            gifDate.centerVertically = YES;
            gifDate.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            gifDate.tag = 103;
            gifDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            gifDate.extendBottomToFit = NO;
            
            
            gifDateString = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\ue003 %@",post[@"date"]]];
            [gifDateString setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:12.0]];
            [gifDateString setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"icomoon" size:10.0] range:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
            [gifDateString setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [gifDateString setTextAlignment:kCTTextAlignmentRight lineBreakMode:kCTLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
            [OHASBasicMarkupParser processMarkupInAttributedString:gifDateString];
            gifDate.attributedText = gifDateString;
            
            if (!(post[@"latitude"] == (id)[NSNull null])){
                //Location of the Post
                gifLocation = [[OHAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165,27,141,21)];
                gifLocation.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
                gifLocation.centerVertically = YES;
                gifLocation.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                gifLocation.tag = 107;
                gifLocation.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                gifLocation.extendBottomToFit = NO;
                
                gifLocationString = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\uf041 %@",post[@"locationName"]]];
                [gifLocationString setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:12.0]];
                [gifLocationString setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"icomoon" size:12.0] range:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
                [gifLocationString setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                [gifLocationString setTextAlignment:kCTTextAlignmentRight lineBreakMode:kCTLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
                [OHASBasicMarkupParser processMarkupInAttributedString:gifLocationString];
                gifLocation.attributedText = gifLocationString;
            }
        }
        
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableBodyIdentifier];
        
        if (cell == nil){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableBodyIdentifier];
        }
        
        //Body of GIF
        // Add more from here http://www.easyapns.com/iphone-emoji-alerts
        gifBody = post[@"body"];
        
        attrLabel = [[OHAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,5,kLabelWidth,tableView.rowHeight-2*kLabelVMargin)];
        attrLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        attrLabel.centerVertically = NO;
        attrLabel.automaticallyAddLinksForType = NSTextCheckingAllTypes;
        attrLabel.delegate = self;
        attrLabel.highlightedTextColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x333333);
        attrLabel.tag = kAttributedLabelTag;
        attrLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        attrLabel.extendBottomToFit = YES;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:attrLabel];
        
        attrLabel = (OHAttributedLabel*)[cell viewWithTag:kAttributedLabelTag];
        mas = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:gifBody];
        [mas setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.0]];
        [mas setTextColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x333333)];
        [mas setTextAlignment:kCTTextAlignmentLeft lineBreakMode:kCTLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [OHASBasicMarkupParser processMarkupInAttributedString:mas];
        attrLabel.attributedText = mas;
    }
        
    else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableActionsIdentifier];
        
        if (cell == nil){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableActionsIdentifier];
        }
        
        [self customizeButtons:btn1];
        btn1.tag = (indexPath.section +1)*200;
        btn1.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"icomoon" size:16.0];
        if ([post[@"is_Favoring"] boolValue]) {
            [btn1 setTitleColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xE4717A) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else{
            [btn1 setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        [btn1 setTitle:@"\uf004" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn1.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        [btn1 addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(favorAction:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:btn1];
        
        
        [self customizeButtons:btn2];
        btn2.tag = (indexPath.section +1)*2000;
        btn2.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"icomoon" size:16.0];
        [btn2 setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn2 setTitle:@"\ue000" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:btn2];
        btn2.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        [btn2 addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(commentAction:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        
        
        [self customizeButtons:btn3];
        btn3.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"icomoon" size:16.0];
        [btn3 setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn3 setTitle:@"\ue001" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn3.tag = (indexPath.section +1)*20000;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:btn3];
        btn3.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        [btn3 addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(otherAction:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
        
        //Paginiation
        if (indexPath.section == [dataArray count]-4 && indexPath.row == 1) {
            [self loadNextPage];
        }
    
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are seeing an image from another cell is that for efficiency's sake, table cells are reused.  To get around this problem, set your image to `nil` after you dequeue the reusable cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: vacawama, something like this?

`__block UIImageView *postGif= (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:104];
            
            postGif.image = nil;`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem, but I see that you are calling `viewWithTag` on the cell in various places and then are adding that view to the cell as a subview again.  If it already a part of the cell, why add it again.  Also, because cells are reused, if you don't ever remove these extra subviews, they will just accumulate.  Are you using Image Builder at all for the prototype cells, or are you doing this entirely in code?

Comment: vacawama, I am using storyborads, let me fix the viewWithTag issue and see if that makes a difference

Comment: vacawama, even that doesnt fix the issue

Comment: Update the edit to show your latest code.  Please describe the behavior you are currently seeing.

Comment: After your image has loaded in the background and you are ready to update the UI, you need to check if that image cell is still visible.  You are checking that before calling `GIFLoader`, but GIFLoader should check this in the main thread after the image has been loaded.  Otherwise, you might be updating the image of another cell that is reusing your first cell (in the case that your cell scrolled off the screen after `GIFLoader` was called).

Comment: With all the changes so far, you are still seeing the behavior where the cell loads up with one image, and then it switches to another image a second or so later?

Comment: yes its still doing the same thing, When I was using webview instead of imageview even then it did that. but back then I though that maybe the webview had a problem, so I switched to imageview, but the problem remains.

Comment: The only thing we haven't seen is GIFLoader.  Could you post that code as well?

Comment: vacawama, please have a look at the edit. also please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031236/wrong-images-are-showing-up-in-uitableviewcell) if you can. He had the same problem like me I am suspecting and our codes look similar as well, but I cannot make any sense of the answer provided.

Comment: I don't think your problem is the same as the link you posted.  That person wasn't using the `cell` returned from dequeReusableCell, but you are.  In your code, I think you should pass `tableView` to load GIF instead of `feedTableView`.  Also, I would add logging to the load GIF to find out which path you hitting to update the image.  You should expect `image` to still be `nil` before setting it in load GIF.  Log if it is not.

Comment: vacawama, I am logging everything now and in the log it seems to be working right, but on the device even the interface is lagging a little, as in moving slowly after awhile. is it maybe because of that? I am not sure why is it lagging as well, the code seems pretty easy and not that resource consuming to me, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I believe you are slowing down over time because you are adding buttons as sub views to the cells but never removing them.  So, over time as the cells get reused, more and more buttons get added until eventually your app will run out of memory.

Comment: fixed the problem, now UI is way faster but that image flickering thing still persists :(

Answer (score 2):

First, you shouldn't be doing all of that stuff in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

You should subclass UITableViewCell and layout the cell in it's own class.

Cell for row at indexPath should load the cell and populate data. Not layout loads of controls.

Second, once you've done this you can call...

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    self.imageView.image = nil;
}
```

This will clear the imageView on dequeue of the cell so that if there is a delay loading hte image then you only see a blank imageView rather than the image that was in there previously.

Comment: Fogmeister, can you please explain that a little more in detail?

Comment: I will update tomorrow. I'm off to bed now. For now though, take a look here at the "Subclassing" header... http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/

Comment: Fogmeister, thanks for the link. I tried that as well, it didnt help